# What is $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{-1}\left(\sin^{2}x\right)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Wolfram Alpha approximates it as $0.955202$. I'm not really sure how to go about solving this. My attempt involved integration by parts.

$$I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^{-1}\left(\sin^{2}x\right)dx=x\sin^{-1}\left(\sin^{2}x\right)-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x\sin2x}{\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}x}\cos x}dx$$

This looks no easier to solve and I am not sure what other tricks I can try with this integral.